# Intuition behind the expectation definition

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

What is the intuition behind the general definition of expectation for a measurable random variable X ? Please help.

[image]

Comment: Generalization of a weighted average is good?

Comment: Peter is there any chance of typing out that general definition? I really can't read it!

Comment: Here is the wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is that integrals with respect to measures are the mathematical generalization of sums.

Consider the example of $X$ being the value of a die roll. Then we know that

$$ E(X) = \frac{1}{6}(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = 3.5$$

This is a **sum**, as we were taught in beginner probability that expectations are sums. But in measure theory we learn that **sums are just a type of integral**. Suppose we view $X$ as being a measurable function on a discrete measure space $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\Sigma$ being the power set of $\Omega$, and with discrete measure $P$ defined by $P(1) = \ldots = P(6) = 1/6$. Then $E(X)$ can also be written as

$$ E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X \, dP $$

as given in your generalized definition. This allows us to generalize expectations to random variables on a continuous domain.

Comment: nice explanation, thanks a lot.